# Google Auth OAuth 2.0 SvelteKit wierd behavior

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, sveltekit

I am using Google Auth OAuth 2.0 One Tap Sign and Sveltekit,
and I got some really weird behavior,
I followed this doc https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview with javascript

```js
onMount(async () => {
    const handleCredentialResponse = async (response) => {
        console.log('Encoded JWT ID token: ' + response.credential);
        };
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: clientId,
        callback: handleCredentialResponse,
    });
    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        document.getElementById('buttonDiv'),
        { theme: 'outline', size: 'large' } // customization attributes
    );
    google.accounts.id.prompt(); 
});
```

the code from the doc.
Sometimes it works everything goes well,
Sometimes I got

- Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: google is not defined
  And some mobile / mobile browsers I get
- [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.
  but works  on laptop

Hope someone can understand and help.
Do we have any way to check logs for investigation?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**I got your code to successfully run without modification:** https://google-signin-kit.vercel.app/ (This app is in "dev" mode so signin may only succeed with my Google account. If you clone my repo and set your Google client id, signin will work for you.)

**I would check how [my code](https://github.com/Leftium/google-signin-kit) is different from your code** outside `onMount()`. For example, how did you include the Google javascript? I describe one major change below.

**You also need to check your Google app settings.** `[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed...` is fixed by adding the *HTTPS* app domain to your Google app "Authorized JavaScript origins." Non-HTTPS domains are not allowed. For example, these domains would not work:

- https://google-signin-kit-leftium.vercel.app/ (Not added as Authorized JavaScript origin)
- http://google-signin-kit.vercel.app/ (Not HTTPS, if Vercel did not automatically redirect to HTTPS)
- Of course, raw IP addresses will not work, either.
- `localhost` is a special exception, but not easy (impossible?) to access from mobile.

---

`ReferenceError: google is not defined` (sometimes) happens because `onMount()`  runs before the Google script is loaded.

- To get a consistent reproduction, USB debug/inspect Android Chrome and set "disable caching" and throttling to "Slow 3G." (I could not reproduce on desktop Chrome).
- Fixed by removing `defer async` when including Google's script: `<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>`
- It should also be possible to [call a function after the script is loaded](https://www.nielsvandermolen.com/external-javascript-sveltejs/), but I got inconsistent results in SvelteKit. For some reason Kit doesn't always call the load function. Possibly a bug?
- Ideally, the Google script should be `import`ed, but I couldn't find a version of the Google script that was built for importing. You may be able to construct a library that you can import? Importing would compile the Google script code into your app, tree-shaking the unused portions. Thus saving a network request and bandwidth.
- Another workaround is to have your `onMount` function check for the `google` variable. If `google` is still undefined, call your function again after a certain timeout.

---

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply,
but the code is running under HTTPS and it still gives me the issue,
the repo has the same code as mine,
This code is running perfectly on https://subs.swapye.com but not on https://swpaye.com
I really don't understand why.

Comment: @PekoChan Your code still has `async defer` when including `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client`, which I recommended removing. (`async defer` *should* cause race conditions in both domains, though.)

If it works on one domain but not the other, I would check that your Google Authorized JavaScript origins are configured correctly.

Comment: I've created ID clients OAuth 2.0 for each domain -> here you can see :
https://bearwallet.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/Screen%20Shot%202022-06-01%20at%2014.37.39.png
as for async defer, I'll try it tonight if it works I'll give you the bounty

as for the async defer, I'll try this evening, I'll keep you updated, thanks trying tho :)

Comment: Also by removing `async defer` it doesn't work, I am about to think that this is related to my domain :/,
thanks a lot for trying anyway.